# UIAlertView message

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm having problem with my `UIAlertView`, Here is how I show it,

```
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"エラー"
                                     message:@"Oneスロットに何も画像が設定されていません"
                                    delegate:nil
                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                           otherButtonTitles:nil];            
[message show];
```

But then the preview looks like this:

[image]

What I wanted is to make it just 1 Line, but I have read in some thread/question that it shouldn't be done, what is the best way to do this without making my app being rejected? I Have read about changing its width, but is this allowed?

Comment: There is no way to control the presentation and layout of UIAlertView other than writing your own substitute. (Cf. tapbots.com). Sorry...

Comment: (Or choose a shorter message)

Comment: You can use one custom UIAlertView available [here](https://github.com/AalokParikh/CustomAlertView). Here you can have control over the font size displayed in alert view so it will help you to show your message in one line, may be this will help you :)

Comment: I have also used a custom `UIAlertView` but my client seem want me to use the traditional `UIAlertView`.

Comment: @Wolvorin, wont this let my app be rejected?

Comment: Nop As I per my knowledge app will not rejected from apple.

Comment: the solutions would be simple: reduce the length of text **or** write an own alert view for yourself **or** try to explain to your client an elephant cannot fit in the shoes-box.